# How do I apply padding to everything but the nav header background width

Tags: html, css, header, padding, nav

I am trying to set up a website where 10% padding applies to each element EXCEPT for the navbar background width (want the black header/navbar to always be 100% while the elements within the header (logo/nav bar) have 10% padding on either side.

I have tried 1. Apply padding to body :excepting navbar background 2. Tried to apply padding separately to every element but the navbar 3. Played around with classes/ids to make the nav bar the top priority. 4. Tried to set negative padding for the header.

I am sure there must be a solution where I can add 10% padding to the body and exclude the nav bar header but I am not finding it :(

Here's the relevant html and css:

```
<nav class="navigation-bar">
      <img class="logo" src="../myFirstWebsite/assets/aperture.svg" alt="Apperture logo">
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">WIKI</a>
        <a href="#">GITHUB</a>
        <a href="#">LINKEDIN</a>         
 </nav>
```

```
body {
    background-image: url(../myFirstWebsite/assets/topography.png);
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
h3, .title, a {
    color: #ff0099; 
}
.navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;  
    height: 80px; 
    background-color: #333333; 
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;    
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.navigation-bar > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 80px;
    float:right;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
*{
   padding:10px;
}
body,html{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
 }
```

Comment: Check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/vpxegwsa/1/

Comment: Heya, I have tried it as well as trying to apply the 
```body{
   padding:0px !important;
   margin:0px !important;
 } ```

but the problem is, I want padding to apply to the logo on the left and the right most navbar link on the right - if I use this it forces those to the edges of the bar and doesn't keep them in line with the rest of the elements. Should be 10% padding for everything BUT the black navbar background - the elements within navbar should be 10% as well

Comment: You can remove !important. It'll still work

Comment: Che the fiddle out i provided in earlier comment

Comment: Or this https://jsfiddle.net/6bvph53d/

Comment: Ah, I see - the padding is to be 10% on both sides not 10px - basically making the content more "centered" and the logo and the right most side of the nav bar alligned with the rest of the content while the header bar stretches to 100% :) Thank you so much for the patience

Comment: vote up will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Need a bit more reputation but "my feedback has been recorded" :)